# smooth scroll to certain element within an element with overflow set to scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Now I know, yes there are heaps of questions on how to smooth scroll to elements on a page yes I know I can use jquery like this..

```
$("#button").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
```

and yes I know I can do this with javascript

```
element.scrollIntoView();
```

but neither of those are giving me the desired result..

Okay so... Is there an easy way to scroll to an element inside a component?

So I have a sidebar and the sidebar has its own scroll outside of the body because its component with the overflow set to scroll.. so what I want to be able to do is scroll to a certain element within that component

I have tried to do..

`scrollIntoView` like so..

```
upNext.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
```

but I find that I cannot get it to scroll to the right place on the element, its buggy and its extra features like `behavior: 'smooth'`dont have great broswer support

So my question is how can I scroll to a certain element within an element with a scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger scroll in the sidebar rather than the document or html

```js
$('#scroll-sidebar').click(function(){
  $('sidebar').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#scroll-here").offset().top
 }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
}
sidebar, main{
  padding: 15px;
}
sidebar{
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
ul > li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
main{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <sidebar>
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Iste, doloribus!</li>
      <li>Labore, animi.</li>
      <li>Adipisci, dolores?</li>
      <li>Odio, excepturi.</li>
      <li>Odio, aliquid!</li>
      <li>Numquam, officia.</li>
      <li>Alias, officiis!</li>
      <li>Tenetur, quas!</li>
      <li>Totam, vitae.</li>
      <li>Dignissimos, at?</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    
    <ul id="scroll-here">
      <li>Iste, doloribus!</li>
      <li>Labore, animi.</li>
      <li>Adipisci, dolores?</li>
      <li>Odio, excepturi.</li>
      <li>Odio, aliquid!</li>
      <li>Numquam, officia.</li>
      <li>Alias, officiis!</li>
      <li>Tenetur, quas!</li>
      <li>Totam, vitae.</li>
      <li>Dignissimos, at?</li>
    </ul>
  </sidebar>
  <main>
    <h1>Main Container</h1>
    <button id="scroll-sidebar">Scroll Sidebar</button>
  </main>
</div>
```